# If statment not working properly?

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript if statement isn't working properly. Keeps coming out false and I cannot figure out why. I hate to not put my text information here when posting this however not much more to say. Here is my code.

Should be returning true since am-pm is equal to true?

> JavaScript

```
$(function($) {

  $('.wordpress-timezone-js-time').each(function() {

        var myUtc = $(this).data('utc');
        var myUtcOffset = $(this).data('utc-offset');
        var myAmPm = $(this).data('am-pm');
        if (myAmPm == 'true'){
            var amPmSet = '%I:%M:%S %p'; // 12 hour
        } else {
            var amPmSet = '%H:%M:%S'; // 24 hour
        }

      $(this).jclock({
        utc: myUtc ,
        utcOffset: myUtcOffset ,
        format: amPmSet,
      })

  })
});
```

> HTML Element

```
<p>EST: <span class="wordpress-timezone-js-time" data-utc="true" data-utc-offset="-5" am-pm="true"></span></p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding "data-" to your "am-pm" attribute like you did for utc-offset. Make it `data-am-pm`.

Comment: if you want to use `data` don't forget to add `data-` as a prefix to your span attribute e.g. `<span data-am-pm="true">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `attr` function if you need to retrieve the attribute value, i.e. :

`$(this).attr('am-pm')`

*Edit, for completeness:*

Or, as others suggested, you could change `am-pm` to `data-am-pm` and keep your call `$(this).data('am-pm')`.

Answer (score 0):

Change you code to this one.

```
<p>EST: <span class="wordpress-timezone-js-time" data-utc="true" data-utc-offset="-5" data-am-pm="true"></span></p>
```

instead of "am-pm" put it as "data-am-pm", if you're using data attribute to fetch the data in javascript. Otherwise $(this).attr('am-pm') is correct.